# How to force boot a 2016 MacBook without battery

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging, power

I have an early 2016 MacBook (not pro or Air) and recently the battery started swelling up and it stopped charging but it continued working with power from the AC adapter.
I can’t afford to have the battery in replaced at the moment.
The AC adapter is a standard 30W Adapter with USB C cable and it seems to power it up until recently. I tried a 60W adapter and it powers it without any issue (this 60W adapter isn’t mine so I don’t have access to it all the time). The problem I have is that the 30W charger powers it up sometimes and other times it doesn’t. I can’t figure out what I do differently when it powers it and when it doesn’t. I would like to find a definite way to always power it with the 30W charger until I can afford to get the battery replaced.

Comment: You do have a backup of your data up to date and on a separate device? If not, then that is seriously a priority.

Comment: One thing you *really* shouldn't be trying to do is push more power through a swollen battery. You're increasing the risk of fire [& less importantly, cracking the screen, keyboard or case]. See https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/What_to_do_with_a_swollen_battery

Comment: You MB has a 41Wh battery, so 30W is a little too low. Try to force your MacBook in Battery Saving mode when on sector in system preferences. This would make it use less power and may be keep it on. Try also to not use high brightness.

Comment: Not really a fix, but if you are ok with extreme performance limitations you could simply remove the battery (this would also ensure no fire hazard) and run it off the AC adapter. It *should* work, but I can't guarantee it for this specific model

Comment: It already runs directly with power. I assume the battery doesn’t work anymore. Whenever it comes on, I see “Battery not charging: power source: AC Adapter. Would taking the battery out make any difference? The laptop goes off once I remove the charger.

Comment: It depends on the model.  You can call Apple and ask them.  Older models didn't have the technology that would disable the battery in a case like this, so removing the battery would make a difference for those models.